# JSON list converter C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, list

I am completely c# beginner. I am trying to convert json data in c#. I am struggling with the list. As long as I am able to convert basic methods, I have an error in that one with the list. Do you mind to give me some advice how to fix my problem?

#### Original JSON data

> [{"data": {"Temperature": {"data": {"2018-07-04 13:05:00": 20.9224991798401}, "meta": {"units": "Celsius", "name": "Temperature", "theme": "Weather"}}}, "latest": "2018-07-04 13:05:00", "sensor_height": -999, "type": "Weather", "base_height": -999, "geom": {"coordinates": [-1.62469, 54.98274], "type": "Point"}, "active": "True", "name": "sportshall_oat", "source": {"document": null, "fancy_name": "BMS", "db_name": "Bms", "third_party": false, "web_display_name": "BMS"}}]

#### Main class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();

            var text = client.DownloadString("http://uoweb1.ncl.ac.uk/api/v1/sensor/live.json?sensor_name=sportshall_oat&api_key=4dopcdjiu3wtzfl32hn94hbf5ubm3q89jbh18iaxaqdzc10nlgbebqqvxqyt3ymydi59fjnyrmuqtgtdxb1sm5msac");

            Rootobject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(text);
            Console.WriteLine("current time = " + ro.Property1);

            Class1 c1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(text);

            Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(text);

            Temperature temperature = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Temperature>(text);
            Console.WriteLine("data = " + temperature.data);

            Data1 d1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data1>(text);

            Meta meta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Meta>(text);

            Geom geom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Geom>(text);

            Source source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Source>(text);

         }
    }
}
```

#### JSON data (generated by Visual studio)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{

    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }
        public string latest { get; set; }
        public int sensor_height { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int base_height { get; set; }
        public Geom geom { get; set; }
        public string active { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Source source { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public Temperature Temperature { get; set; }
    }

    public class Temperature
    {
        public Data1 data { get; set; }
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data1
    {
        public float _20180704130500 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public string units { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string theme { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geom
    {
        public float[] coordinates { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public object document { get; set; }
        public string fancy_name { get; set; }
        public string db_name { get; set; }
        public bool third_party { get; set; }
        public string web_display_name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

When I am trying to run my program the console is crushed. After debugging I can tell where the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. There is the error message

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ConsoleApp2.Rootobject'
>   because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
>   deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The square brackets `[]` around the JSON indicate that it's an array. In this case deserializing to a `List<RootObject>` is the most common solution, so `var ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(text);`

Comment: @Equalsk More like `List<Class1>` but yes, fundamentally correct :)

Comment: After deserializing the JSON once you wan't have to do any further deserialization, you'll simply be able to access everything from the initial class.

Comment: @DavidG Just checking everyone else is awake, honest...

Comment: Well done! This was your first question and you provided all the relevant information we needed to a help you. You'd be amazed how many people don't manage that on their first try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your code.

1. Since the JSON is surrounded by `[...]`, it means it's an array or items so you need to use a `List` (or similar) structure. In your case, you can drop the `Rootobject` class completely and deserialise directly to a `List<Class1>`. For example:

   ```
   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(json);
   ```
2. The `Data1` class is using a date as the property name. I would suggest dropping that class completely and modify thre `Temperature` class to use a `Dictonary<DateTime, float>`:

   ```
   public class Temperature
   {
       public Dictionary<DateTime, float> data { get; set; }
       public Meta meta { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   And now you can cope with any `DateTime` being passed in, you would use it like this:

   ```
   var data = obj[0].data.Temperature.data;
   Console.WriteLine($"The temperature on {data.Key} was {data.Value}");
   ```

Comment: Good call on the `Temperature` class!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I changed my classes as you suggested.

Comment: @Monika No problem. Don't forget to vote and accept answers as you find appropriate. Oh, and nice to meet another person in Newcastle!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't vote as my reputation is below the 15. Nice to meet!

Comment: @Monika you can select the tick next to the answer which helped you best (I'd suggest this one is the right one!). That's not voting its marking the accepted (to you) answer.

Comment: @DavidG I just realised that after my changing in the code I got the error "Error CS1061 'Dictionary<DateTime, float>' does not contain a definition for '_20180704130500' and no extension method '_20180704130500' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<DateTime, float>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" . So it is about that Data1 class which you suggested to drop. So probably that's the reason why I don't see the current date and temperature as an output.

Comment: @Monika I've added an example of how you would use the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Your `RootObject` is wrong, and `Class1` is badly named but it is essentially the right structure to deserialize the data - however the data is an array of `Class1`'s. You can use a `List<Class1>` or `Class1[]` (array) - either should work:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var text = client.DownloadString("http://uoweb1.ncl.ac.uk/api/v1/sensor/live.json?sensor_name=sportshall_oat&api_key=4dopcdjiu3wtzfl32hn94hbf5ubm3q89jbh18iaxaqdzc10nlgbebqqvxqyt3ymydi59fjnyrmuqtgtdxb1sm5msac");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(text);
```

You dont need to separately deserialize all the sub parts, eg you can do this:

```
var name = result[0].name;
```

(Note: your list has a single item so you need to ask the list for item with index `0`, and then whatever property you're after)

I wont repeat the warning about your `Temperature` class, but see [@DavidG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51176650/219661)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still not sure about the last line "var name = result.name;" . Do you mind to explain me what should I write instead of "name" to display the data inside the console? I was trying to call the Temperature method to display the temperature, but I got the error message that "Temperature" is not a part of Class1

Comment: @Monika That was just to demonstrate that once deserialized, you could read any properties. To get the `Temperature` it is within the `Data` class so `result.data.Temperature`. To write to the console you use the very intuitively named `Console.WriteLine(result.data.Temperature);` method. Hope that helps

Comment: Ok so that's what I was trying to run. I wrote var temp = result.data.Temperature; and then Console.WriteLine(temp); but the word "data" was highlited with the error: "List<Class1>' does not contain a definitaiton for 'data' and do extension method 'data' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Class1>' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: oooh, sorry my bad. Your list has 1 item. `var temp = result[0].data.Temperature;` @Monika

Comment: Ok that make sense. So I was expecting to see as an output the current date and temperature but the only output is "ConsoleApp2.Temperature". Does it mean that my class with JSON data is written incorrectly?

Comment: I am sorry for lots of questions right now. I spent all day trying to fix my problem and now I really want to understand how it works, not only get the right answers.

Answer (score -2):

Then you need a model. Based on your JSON it will result in something like this.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public DateTime latest { get; set; }
    public int sensor_height { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int base_height { get; set; }
    public Geom geom { get; set; }
    public string active { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Source source { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Temperature Temperature { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}

public class Geom
{
    public float[] coordinates { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Source
{
    Public string document { get; set; }
    Public string fancy_name { get; set; }
    Public string db_name { get; set; }
    Public string third_party { get; set; }
    Public string web_display_name { get; set; }
}

public class Temperature 
{
    public string data { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    Public string units { get; set; }
    Public string name { get; set; }
    Public string theme { get; set; }
}
```

After the creation of a model you simply use this.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(your_json_string);
```

Then you can access to the objects like this:

```
result.data..
result.latest...
```

and so on.

Comment: This won't work for exactly the same reason OP has their actual problem

Comment: And your code still has the same problem as the original code. Look at the 2 previous answers